# Stored procedure select for json data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been struggling how to format my stored procedure to create a json string data

I have this sample query where in i need to format the json string like this

> {"Summary":"Employee change username","DateModified":"2017/09/06","Changes":[{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"1"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"2"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"3"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"4"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"5"}]}

```
DECLARE @membersJSON NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[1,2,3,4,5]';
DECLARE @commiteeID INT = 10;
DECLARE @jsonData NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @jsonTable TABLE(
    Property nvarchar(max),
    old nvarchar(max),
    new nvarchar(max));

INSERT INTO @jsonTable SELECT 'test' as Property,@commiteeID AS old,m.value AS new
FROM OPENJSON(@membersJSON) as m;

SELECT * FROM @jsonTable FOR JSON PATH, ROOT ('CommitteeMembers')
```

Currently my output is still like this

> {"CommitteeMembers":[{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"1"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"2"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"3"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"4"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"5"}]}

Heres the dbfiddle [link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=24e1ef62e75294b2cc2c70544f02430a)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use a cursor here

```
 declare @new_Cursor as CURSOR 
 declare @Property varchar(10)   
 declare @oldValue varchar(10)   
 declare @newValue varchar(10)   
 declare @jsonResult nvarchar(max) ='{"CommitteeMembers":['
set @new_Cursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM @jsonTable FOR JSON PATH, ROOT 
('CommitteeMembers')
    OPEN @new_Cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM @new_Cursor INTO @Property,@oldValue,@newValue
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
      if(@jsonResult<>'{"CommitteeMembers":[') --To separate the objects
          begin
               set @jsonResult = @jsonResult + ','
          end 
      set @jsonResult = @jsonResult + 
'{"Property":"'+@Property+'","old":"'+@oldValue+'","new":"'+@newValue+'"}'
 FETCH NEXT FROM @new_Cursor INTO @Property,@oldValue,@newValue
    end
    CLOSE @new_Cursor
   DEALLOCATE @new_Cursor
   set @jsonResult = @jsonResult + ']}'

  select @jsonResult as Result
```

Update

The issue is with your select Statement

[image: Working img] 
[image]

Comment: CURSOR is not allowed in FOR JSON statement - thats the error

Comment: see the dbdiffle link here http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=db2669c3863b41db46391a0f55e8bc60

Comment: @SecretCoder i got the result correctly check images out

Comment: no i want to add "Summary":Employee change blah blah","Date Modified":"2017/09/06" on the json data. I already achieve the committeemembers json but i want to append Summary and date modified

Comment: yeah whatever mate the issue is in your select statement you fix that and it would work SELECT * FROM @jsonTable FOR JSON PATH, ROOT ('CommitteeMembers') ..hthis was the culprit ,sjust modify the cursor accordingly and it would work

Comment: i did not understand you. i want the result to be like this {"Summary":"Employee change username","DateModified":"2017/09/06","Changes":[{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"1"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"2"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"3"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"4"},{"Property":"test","old":"10","new":"5"}]}

Comment: ok then before running the cursor just fetch those values in the @jsonResult var